# Transfer SCP Cloud User Information securely to ABAP

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-cloud-platform

I have a UI5 Application hosted on SAP NEO which retrieves Data via an ABAP OData Service.

Users are maintained in SAP Cloud Identity and mapped with their Backenduser and the login is setup via Principal Propagation. This is all setup and works.

I got requested to change the Application to enable External Sales Representatives without SAP Backend Users to use the application.

The idea is to use one "technical user" with Basic Authentication instead of Principal Propagation.

My question is what would be the way to identify the original Cloud Username in ABAP(since there sy-uname would be a technical user).

- Debugging in ABAP didn't reveal the original information and I am afraid the original User is not even passed to the Gateway
- The SAP Cloud User API (https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/1de599bf722446849d2b2e10132df42a.html) is not an option because the request could be manipulated in the browser
- I heard of another option using a Java Servlet. But I am afraid that means we have to setup there the whole OData Service again and with every change in the Gateway we have to adjust the Java Servlet as well, or is there maybe a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *Mobile Services* of SAP Cloud Platform, you can activate a header with the username to be transferred to your ABAP system. It's called **X-SMP-ENDUSERNAME**.

Ref the documentation at https://help.sap.com/viewer/38dbd9fbb49240f3b4d954e92335e670/Cloud/en-US/defdadb71ee2476691d987689e3703a2.html

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use Mobile Services for this App, its hosted directly. This ENDUSERNAME Header would be exactly what I need but in a Standard HTML5 App.

Comment: There is a small license fee to run Mobile Services but it's a very easy configuration for this case. The other option to explore is to run OAuth towards SAP Gateway from SCP and map some assertion attributes towards principal attributes. Not sure though if you actually get them in the DPC class.

Comment: I am not too experienced with the Mobile Services. But I thought is for Native or Hybrid Apps. Would it still be possible to upload a UI5 App there and get a normal Link for the Browser with this approach? This should behave like a normal HTML5 Page and not run in a Container or as an App.

Comment: Yes. There is an onboarding process where each device/user gets registered but other than that it's just another URL for the destination. You don't have to use the offline capabilities. You can test it out in Postman.

Comment: Onboarding is not something I can introduce here. The expectation is that the UI5 App works via Browser Link without the need to install an App. And also that new users can be easily onboarded by just activating them in the Identity Provider

Comment: Onboarding happens automatically. Just try it out in a trial account if you don't have the license?

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I finally understood the approach and it works very good :). I created a new Application with the Propagate User Name, changed the destination in my App to the Mobile Services API and was able to fetch the User in the Backend.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can get cloud user ID within your UI5 application and in case you access backend via Odata model you can use ODataModel.setHeaders function to provide your custom request headers which will be attached to every request sent to the backend. I would try to send cloud user id in some custom header value.

And on ABAP side you can use DP facade interface in service implementation to read custom headers:

```
lo_facade ?= /iwbep/if_mgw_conv_srv_runtime~get_dp_facade( ).
lt_client_headers = lo_facade->get_request_header( ).
```

Comment: It would be possible to get the User in the UI5 App and add it to the Header. This option however would not be tamperproof. The Headers could be manipulated in the Chrome Dev Tools for example.

Comment: Encrypt headers with periodically changing key? Not a cure but at least can slow down bad guys for a moment.

Comment: Not sure if it can be the answer, but probably you can use Assertion attribute with principal propagation and use this to tranfer original user id? See here: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/05/28/principal-propagation-using-a-saml-assertion-attribute-as-sap-identifier/